# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' while saving DataFrame to xls

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-excel, xls, nonetype

I have a DataFrame received by `.concat` and I am to save it as xls file, but I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'` Here is a screen of my Dataframe and my code for xls: [image: screen]

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xls', engine='xlsxwriter')
data = data.to_excel(writer)
data.save()
```

in which moment and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/. We also need the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. In any case, the issue is completely trivial, and can be solved by reading the documentation for `to_excel()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pandas `to_excel` method returns None.

```
data = data.to_excel(writer)
```

This overwrites your dataframe with `None`, which doesn't have a `save()` function.

Try doing this, which should work:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xls', engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Comment: now it gives me this: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Ah, it should be writer.save() instead of data.save()

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Pandas 1.3, the method to save the Excel file has changed from save to close. So, please try replacing `writer.save()` with `writer.close()` and see if it works.